# linux wifi 802.11n messup

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Scenario is as follows: my laptop has 3 wifi ifaces, 2 usb (both running on driver rt2800usb and chipset Ralink RT2870/RT3070), and one embedded iwlwifi, intel chipset).

On `iwconfig`, both usb cards show 802.11bgn, whereas intel one shows 802.11abgn.

Yet, when I run `iwlist <iface> freq`, intel cards show N-band channels (36,40,...,104,...); but on both usb cards show only non-N-band channels (1..13).

So, when I set monitor mode on any of the usb cards, and try a N-band channel (as 104), it gets fixed on channel 13.

Why is this happening? How can I get them to work in 5Ghz channels?

Thank u so much!!

Comment: Welcome to Security SE! I'm voting to migrate this question as it does not relate to information security.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly disagree, for it is related to wireless security.

Comment: monitor mode has information security-related uses, but the question does not have security context.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Ralink RT2870/RT3070 chipset actually works on 5GHz channels? A quick google search tells me that the RT3070, which is the transceiver chip is 2.4 GHz only.

When a chipset advertises **IEEE802.11(n)** it does not necessarily mean that it supports dual band 2.4GHz and 5GHz Wi-Fi.

Typically when you look at what legacy standards the chipset supports, you normally can tell without looking into the datasheet, if an **IEEE802.11(n)** chipset is either only 2.4GHz or dual band.

When you only see support for the legacy 2.4 GHz **IEEE802.11(b)** and **IEEE802.11(g)** standards, then it typically is a 2.4GHz chipset.
When you additionally also observe support for the 5 GHz legacy **IEEE802.11(a)** standard, this typically means that your chipset supports both 2.4 and 5 GHz.